# Load CSV Strings With Different Types into Pandas Dataframe, Split Columns, Parse Date

Tags: python, csv, datetime, pandas, time-series

I have two questions concerning a large csv file which contains data in the following way formatted as strings:

```
 "XAU=,XAU=,XAG=,XAG="  
 "25/08/2014 6:00:05,1200.343,25/08/2014 6:00:03,19.44,"            
 "25/08/2014 6:00:05,1200,,,"
```

Is there a way to efficiently load this into a pandas dataframe object? Alternatively, also multiple pandas Series objects would do the job. So far I tried:

```
df = read_csv(path, header=None)
df[0].str[0:-1].str.split(',', return_type='frame')
```

The second line is an answer from this thread [pandas split string into columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29370211/pandas-split-string-into-columns). However, I wonder if there is an even better way, especially since I have different data types? Secondly, how can I correctly parse the dates with `to_datetime()`. I tried to reindex `df` and used `df.index = df.index.to_datetime()`. This worked only half way because it did not strictly keep the `dd/mm/yyyy ...` format. Some dates were incorrectly parsed as `mm/dd/yyyy ...`. I'm looking for fast ways because eventually I will loop over many such csv's. Thx for any help!

EDIT: Ideally data in this form should be handled as well:

```
     "XAU=,XAU=,XAG=,XAG="  
     "25/08/2014 6:00:05,1200.343,25/08/2014 6:00:03,19.44,"            
     ",,25/08/2014 6:00:05,19.50,"
```

So with the answer provided below,

```
    data = StringIO(
    '''
    "XAU=,XAU=,XAG=,XAG="  
    "25/08/2014 6:00:05,1200.343,25/08/2014 6:00:03,19.44,"            
    ",,25/08/2014 6:00:05,19.5,"
    ''')
```

df would become:

```
                  XAU                    XAU                       XAG      XAG
0  25/08/2014 6:00:05               1200.343        25/08/2014 6:00:03    19.44
1                   ,     25/08/2014 6:00:05                      19.5       \n
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can preprocess everything inside the [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) as shown:

```
import csv

data = StringIO(
'''
"XAU=,XAU=,XAG=,XAG="  
"25/08/2014 6:00:05,1200.343,25/08/2014 6:00:03,19.44,"            
"25/08/2014 6:00:05,1200,,,"
''')

df = pd.read_csv(data, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, index_col=False, escapechar='"',   \
                 parse_dates=[0, 2]).rename(columns=lambda x: x.split("=")[0])
df
```

[image]

```
df.dtypes

XAU    datetime64[ns]
XAU           float64
XAG    datetime64[ns]
XAG           float64
dtype: object
```

**Break-up:**

*quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE* : Instructs writer objects to never quote fields

*index_col=False*: Do not use the first column as the index

*escapechar=*": string used to escape delimiter

*parse_dates=[0, 2]*: convert columns(0,2 → order) to `datetime` objects

---

To read a subset of the columns, you can do so with the help of `usecols` by supplying appropriate integer indices as shown:

```
df = pd.read_csv(data, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, index_col=False, escapechar='"',   \
                 parse_dates=[0], usecols=[0,1]).rename(columns=lambda x: x.split("=")[0])

df
```

[image]

If you want to convert the two columns of `XAU` into a series object:

```
df.columns = df.columns + [str('_%d'%(i)) for i in list(range(len(df.columns)))]

ser = pd.Series(data=df['XAU_1'].values, index=df['XAU_0'].values, name='XAU')
ser

2014-08-25 06:00:05    1200.343
2014-08-25 06:00:05    1200.000
Name: XAU, dtype: float64

type(ser)
pandas.core.series.Series
```

---

The reason that fails for a newer case is because `escapechar` skips the first delimiter, as a result the empty strings aren't captured properly.

If that's the case, you are better off ignoring `escapechar` altogether and continuing as shown:

For the combination of old and new data:

```
data = StringIO(
'''
"XAU=,XAU=,XAG=,XAG="   
"25/08/2014 6:00:05,1200.343,25/08/2014 6:00:03,19.44," 
"25/08/2014 6:00:05,1200,,,"
",,25/08/2014 6:00:05,19.50,"       
''')


df = pd.read_csv(data, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, index_col=False, na_values=[""], 
                 parse_dates=[2]).rename(columns=lambda x: x.strip('"').split("=")[0])

old_cols = df.columns
# Index(['XAU', 'XAU', 'XAG', 'XAG'], dtype='object')

new_cols = [col[0] for col in list(enumerate(df.columns))]
# [0, 1, 2, 3]
df.columns = new_cols

# Converting first column to datetime dtype
df[0] = pd.to_datetime(df[0].str.replace('"', ''))   
df.columns = old_cols

df
```

[image]

```
df.dtypes

XAU    datetime64[ns]
XAU           float64
XAG    datetime64[ns]
XAG           float64
dtype: object
```

Comment: Just curious, would it be possible to only read, let's say, the two "XAU" columns in a dataframe or directly in a pandas Series object?

Comment: Yes, it is possible to select a limited number of columns to be read into the dataframe(*See edited response*).

Comment: Unfortunately I encountered a subtle problem. When the data arrives in the following form (slightly diff.):                                                           '''                                                  
"XAU=,XAU=,XAG=,XAG="  
"25/08/2014 6:00:05,1200.343,25/08/2014 6:00:03,19.44,"            
",,25/08/2014 6:00:05,19.50,"
'''                                                                                                               the df will contain a semicolon as a value for seond row and first column. As a result, the data won't be alligned properly.

Comment: Consequently, the date parsing fails as well.

Comment: Ps. I edited my question at the end. So it's just a slight change of the incoming data string.

Comment: The code has been modified to suit such purposes. *See edit*

Comment: That's great, thank you a lot. It works fine now. Only as a last remark, I wonder if it's also possible to specify the dtype of the price quotes by column index, such that pandas does's need to infer it? Generally speaking, is it wise to read data from such "string like" format (this is how it's provided to me)?

Comment: Yes, you could specify the `dtype` during reading operation itself by passing a `dict` of column names/column order as keys and the types as values of the key-value pair. Like, `dtype={1:np.float64. 3:np.float64}`, where 1 and 3 correspond to the price columns.

Comment: It's better if you could strip off those double quotes as it does not give any additional information and only leads to confusion as we just saw earlier. Read about `csv.reader` which you could use to make such modifications prior to using `read_csv` module of `pandas`.

Comment: Indeed, I can read and collect each row as a "full string" in a list and perform the following: `data = StringIO("\n".join(ListWithRowsAsStrings))`